# Firefox Dropdown Bookmarks menu disappears when quitting "Customize"

Tags: 12.04, firefox

I'm using Firefox 23.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit. I'm having this annoying problem that when I select view-->customize and drag the dropdown bookmarks menu to the bookmarks toolbar, it disappears the moment I quit customize.

I've started Firefox in safemode to make sure it's not an add-on problem, purged and reinstalled it, created new user profile (moved .mozilla directory) and purged ubufox; none of these things helped.

The Bookmarks Toolbar is enabled. I want to put the drop-down bookmark menu (it's a button) on that toolbar. I go to customize and drag it onto the toolbar, but the moment I click "done" it disappears. If I go to customize again I still see it on the toolbar, but the moment I quite customize it disappears again.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Thanks for the edits and the comments Jorge! I'd try to learn how to ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple trick that works and doesn't require any extension :

1. In about:config, set ui.use_unity_menubar to false
2. In the View > Tool bars menu, a new Menubar item is now available. Uncheck this item.
3. In about:config, set ui.use_unity_menubar to true again
4. Profit!

Comment: Note that this has the effect of making the tabs appear 2px closer to the title bar when Firefox is started. When the Unity global menu is clicked, the tabs then move down (and stay down till Firefox is restarted). A minor issue, but one that was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

In top menu alongside "file" and "edit", click on show > tool bars > bookmark.

I may be wrong cause not sure if i understood your problem

Comment: Sorry, I think you've misunderstood. The Bookmarks Toolbar is enabled. I want to put the drop-down bookmark menu (it's a button) on that toolbar. I go to customize and drag it onto the toolbar, but the moment I click "done" it disappears. If I go to customize again I still see it *on the toolbar*, but the moment I quite customize it disappears again.

Answer (score 0):

The TOOLBAR isn't missing.  It's the dropdown bookmarks menu ICON that you can see in the customize menu, and even place. But when the customize menu is closed the icon simply vanishes.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Firefox 23.0 made a design decision that merges some bookmark buttons together, and further merges those with the Bookmarks Toolbar. This caused the drop-down Bookmarks icon to disappear (merge).

I installed the Classic Bookmark Button add-on and that fixed the problem. After installation I had a new Bookmarks button in the customize menu, which I was able to drag onto the Bookmarks toolbar.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me :)